# keeping elements in dynamic array

Tags: c++

how to keep my integers in dynamic array? first, i need to ask user to inout amount of numbers in array and then store all of them there.

```
int n;
cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
cin >> n;
int input;
int* array;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Enter your integer:" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    array = new int[input];
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

in the end it shows only some garbage values. what's wrong?

Comment: Hint: in the correct version of this program, `new` does not appear inside a loop.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: You obviously don't know how to use arrays in C++. Read some first, come back with real problems.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of `new` in (dynamic) array; you are using
`array = new int[input];` as if this would append a new slot to an array and set the value then to `input`.

Do two steps:

First, as soon as you know how many items the array shall hold, reserve memory for it (e.g. like `array = new int[amountOfValues]`).

Then, for each value entered, place assign it at the correct position in the array (e.g. by `array[i] = someValue`; make sure that `i` is less than `amountOfValues`).

Answer (score 0):

I see at least three approaches. The first one is the following

```
int n;
cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
cin >> n;
int input;

int* array = new int[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Enter your integer:" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    array[i] = input; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}

// ...

delete [] array;
```

The second one is the following

```
#include <memory>

//...

int n;
cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
cin >> n;
int input;

std::unique_ptr<int[]> array( new int[n] );

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Enter your integer:" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    array[i] = input; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

And the third one is the following

```
#include <vector>

//...

int n;
cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
cin >> n;
int input;

std::vector<int> array( n );

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Enter your integer:" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    array[i] = input; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem simply you are trying to put your numbers values into size of your array and you are not storing them inside it.

also in each iteration you initialize array with the inputs values `array = new int[input];`

so it will reserve size from memory in each iteration according to your inputs values and when you print array values the results will be garbage values from memory because you didn't store any value in your array.

your program should be like :

```
 int n;
 cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
 cin >> n;
 int input;
 int* array;
 array = new int[n];
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Enter your integer:" << endl;
        cin >> input; 
        array[i] = input;   
 }
```